# JfileChooser wont show image selected inside Jpanel

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, jfilechooser

I am having no luck getting an image to show in a Jpanel when selected using Java's JFileChooser. I also want the selected image to be automatically resized and fit the set size of my Jpanel?

Here is the code i have written so far. The JfileChooser is shown in a new JFrame and i want to also close this Jframe when an image is successfully uploaded and viewable in Jpanel.

Here is the Upload Button that should open the JFileChooser, allow file to be selected and then upload the image (to be resized, NEED HELP IN HOW TO MAKE IMAGE AUTOMATICALLY RESIZED), then close the Jframe "frame" when the image is show in the Jpanel "PicturePanel"?

EDIT: ADDED A SSCCE of what i am trying to accomplish.

I want to after the  "upload" button click, show the image sized appropriately (MUST FIT THE JPANEl "Picture panel") Show the image in the Black bordered panel.

```
import classes.BackgroundPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class Test   {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    JButton button = new JButton();
    button.setText("Upload");
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Frame");
    final JFrame imageFrame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    final Test_Image t = new Test_Image();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JPanel picturePanel = new JPanel();
 //  chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
      Dimension d = new Dimension(1261, 765);
      Dimension d2 = new Dimension(1300, 900);
      picturePanel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));
      panel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));
      Dimension d3 = new Dimension(343, 247);
      picturePanel.setSize(d3);
        //picturePanel.setSize(d);
      panel.add(button);
      panel.setSize(d3);


    //panel.setVisible(true);
   //panel.add(picturePanel);

   button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(chooser.showOpenDialog(imageFrame) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

                try {
                    Image bi = ImageIO.read(
                    chooser.getSelectedFile());
                    BackgroundPanel bp = new BackgroundPanel(bi);
                    if (bi != null)
                    bp.setImage(bi);
                    else
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(imageFrame,
                    "File is not an image!");
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(imageFrame,
                    "Error Reading File!");
                 }                
            }                              

        }
    });      


  frame.setSize(d2);
  frame.add(picturePanel).setLocation(100, 100);
  frame.add(panel);
  frame.setVisible(true);

 }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

When dynamically removing/adding components the basic code should be:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

I don't know if this is the problem because you didn't post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Post a proper SSCCE if you need more help.

> NEED HELP IN HOW TO MAKE IMAGE AUTOMATICALLY RESIZED),

Then you can't use a JLabel. You need to do custom painting and use the Graphics.drawImage(....) method.

You can take a look at the [Background Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) which allows you to draw an image scaled or tiled (among other things).

Comment: I dont know of any other part of my code i could possibly post. You mentioned custom painting, is this creating a new class extending the Graphics class? if i have the panel size can i set the image size using the drawImage() method?

Comment: Did you read the SSCCE link? How is the code you posted compileable. How do we execute the code and click on a button since you never added the button to a frame? I gave you an example of custom painting. Download the class and create a SSCCE that just uses that BackgroundPanel class with an image. Then you can follow the code to see how it works.

Comment: Okay, Thank you for the help. I created a test class and used the BackgroundPanel class to display and Image, here is the functionality i am trying to achieve following the same structure. I have a card-layout panel application and on that panel i have a button (upload image) that when clicked shows the FileChooser in a seperate Jframe. Back in my application, i added a another JPanel (will replace with Background Panel) that is going to show the uploaded image. if there is any way i can show you a screenshot of this view please let me know.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. The BackgroundPanel class has a setImage() method so you can easily change the image once you read in the image after choosing a file. A screeshot doesn't help, that is why you need to post a SSCCE.

Comment: i will re-create the error i am getting using a simple Frame and a Panel while adding the above button to my Frame. Thanks